# clickable div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to make my div tag clickable, but i cant find out whats the problem.
Its a five star rating system, where the stars is giving different values. from 1 to 5.

On mouse over div tag is changing image, but wont give me any result when clicking.

my div tag

```
  <div id="5"  OnClick="SendRating(value);" onmouseover=rateStar(id) value="5" ><img src="star.jpg"></div>


function rateStar(rating){
    var i = 1;
    var ratings = '';
    for (i==1; i<=5; i++){
        if (i<=rating){
            document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = '<img src=\"star1.gif\">';
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById(i).innerHTML = '<img src=\"star.jpg\">';
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my sendrating function

```
function SendRating(RatingValue){
var paramas = "rating="+RatingValue;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
  url: "rating.php",
  data: paramas,
    success: function(responseText)
    {
    document.getElementById("ContentHolder").innerHTML = responseText;
    }
  }
);
}
```

Comment: Where is the send rating method?

Comment: where is the SendRating function?

Comment: try using sendRating(this) instead

Comment: Div elements have neither a `value` nor a `text` property.

Comment: @Quentin yeah Quentin...I thought it was a input...sorry, deleted the comment =)

Comment: `<a>` elements don't have `value` or `text` properties either!

Comment: Will edit my questions since I cant manage my mouse overfuction work when the value is working =/

Answer (score 3):

`onclick` you call the function `SendRating` with one argument — `value` — but you never define that variable.

You also have a number of errors in the HTML, you should [validate it](http://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 0):

get the star rating value from the id and use it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function clicked(item) {
    alert($(item).attr("id"));
   }
  </script>


  <div onclick="sendRating(this);" id="5">test</div>
```

you can also try using the following

```
<div id="3" onClick="sendRating(this.id)">B3</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendRating(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i==1; i<=5; i++){
```

should be:

```
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++){
```

and, `OnClick` should be all lowercase,

Answer (score -1):

As stated earlier the HTML cannot find your JavaScript function. But also note that you have not nested in the JS funciton inside <script type="text/javascript">...</script> tags. So the function declaration is interpreted by the browser as text, and not as JavaScript.

Some tips on the HTML: All attributes should be lower-case, and their value should be inside double-quotes.

Comment: HTML attribute names are not case-sensitive, and their values may use either `"` or `'` or (in some cases) no quotes at all.

Comment: Browsers understand them, yes. But it's much cleaner code if you do things consistently. One of his attributes is "OnClick" and another is "onmouseover".

Comment: Besides, my answer was more about the JavaScript function not being in a JavaScript "area". The HTML was simply a side-note.